# DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate: Click on element in row sets focus on row but not on the element itself

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a DataGrid with a RowDetailsTemplate. In the Details Template there is a Textbox inside a DataGridColumn. When i want to set the focus on the textbox by clicking it, first the Row is selected. Only with the second click i can select the textbox itself. Is there a good way to capture the first click event just in xaml and select the textbox manually?

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBox Grid.Column="0"/>
          <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns
   </DataGrid>
  </DataTemplate>
 </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Comment: In the focus changed event could you handle the event, and then manually pass focus to the textbox?

Comment: Should work by default. Please provide a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: @mm8 i added some information. Could this behaviour caused by the fact that the cell is placed in the RowDetails?

Comment: Have you tried with `SelectionUnit` property mentioned in answered by me

Answer (score 0):

```html
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone">
   <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
           <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate>
                       <TextBox Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
       </Style>
   </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

At the moment, I clicked the first time. From the first click goes into edit mode.

Comment: Ive got a DataGridTemplateColumn. I edited my question and added a code snippet to make it more clear

Comment: I copied your code to my column. From the first click immediately goes to edit.

Comment: Make <DataGrid Focusable = "False" and your DataTemplate Grid too

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`SelectionUnit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionunit?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of `DataGrid` and set value `Cell` like this:

```
<DataGrid SelectionUnit="Cell" >
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="0"/>
           <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    YourStuff here
</DataGrid>
```